# "Live" data in XAML editor window in Visual Studio and running application

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am trying implementing an addin for SparxEA with the MVVM Light. One thing that I found interesting is seeing “live” data in a window as is mentioned in the course of MVVM Light. So, I would like to do the same. As I have Class Library project I can’t use App.XAML.

In XAML I have this code:

```
<Window x:Class="GoatJira.View.About"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GoatJira.View"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:GoatJira.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="{Binding Path=AboutTitle}" Height="322.613" Width="573.608" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Initialized="Window_Initialized"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=AboutData}}"
    >

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewmodel:AboutViewModel x:Key="AboutData"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
…
```

This perfectly works within Visual Studio IDE. When I run the app and want to instantiate the window, I obtain this exception (translated from Czech): *Source marked as AboutData was not found. Names of sources are case sensitive.*

When I remove the 10th line with DataContext, I can’t see the bind data within the VS, on the other hand, application works fine when I assign the DataContext in code. My understanding is, that there is a way when it works in VS and in running app without changing anything.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

If needed, the whole code is at https://github.com/SlavekRydval/GoatJira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you move the DataContext to after the resource section i.e.

```
<Window blah=for>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewmodel:AboutViewModel x:Key="AboutData"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

 <Window.DataContext>
      <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="AboutData"/>
</Window.DataContext>
```